# Cakephp contain and belongsTo hasMany conditions

Tags: cakephp, find, belongs-to, contain

From the CakePHP manual:

```
  Let's say you had a belongsTo relationship between Posts and Authors. Let's say you wanted to find all the posts that contained a certain keyword ("magic") or were created in the past two weeks, but you want to restrict your search to posts written by Bob:

array (
    "Author.name" => "Bob", 
"OR" => array (
    "Post.title LIKE" => "%magic%",
    "Post.created >" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks"))
)
)
```

However, its not working for me.  I've got Scrapes belongsTo Vargroup, and Vargroup hasMany Scrape.  My scrapes table has a field vargroup_id

When I do:

```
$this->Vargroup->contain('Scrape');
$this->Vargroup->find('first');
```

I get:

```
Array
(
[Vargroup] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16950
        [item_id] => 1056
        [image] => cn4535d266.jpg
        [price] => 22.95
        [instock] => 1
        [timestamp] => 2012-10-29 11:35:10
    )

[Scrape] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 18163
                [item_id] => 1056
                [vargroup_id] => 16950
                [timestamp] => 2012-05-23 15:24:31
                [instock] => 1
                [price] => 22.95
            )
    )
)
```

But when I do :

```
$this->Vargroup->contain('Scrape');
$this->Vargroup->find('first', array(
'conditions' => array(
    'not' => array(
    array('Scrape.timestamp >' => $today)   
    )
)
));
```

Im getting The following error with associated sql output

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Scrape.timestamp' in 'where clause'
Query: SELECT `Vargroup`.`id`, `Vargroup`.`item_id`, `Vargroup`.`image`, `Vargroup`.`price`, `Vargroup`.`instock`, `Vargroup`.`timestamp` FROM `vargroups` AS `Vargroup`   WHERE `Scrape`.`timestamp` = '2012-10-29
```

It doesn't look like its binding the table at all.. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 $this->Vargroup->contain('Scrape');
 $this->Vargroup->find('first', array(
   'conditions' => array(
   'not' => array(
      'Scrape.timestamp >' => array($today)   
      )
   )
 ));
```

i think this examples from cakephp page tell the right way to do a "not" condition,
check it out.

```
 array(
     "NOT" => array("Post.title" => array("First post", "Second post", "Third post"))
 )
```

this is the complex find conditions page if you have more questions. [Cakephp complex find conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.  Although I see you did fix an error I had with the extra array.  Thx.