# cakephp find with contain belongsTo condition

Tags: cakephp, find, contain

This is the situations:

A Cart belongsTo Product. A Product belongsTo a Category.

This is my query:

```
$results = $this->Cart->find('all', 
        array(
          'contain' => array(
                'Product' => array('Category')
                 ),
          'conditions'=>array(
                               'OR' => array(
                                    'Product.title LIKE' => "%$query%", 
                                    'Category.name LIKE' => "%$query%"
                                     )
                             ),                                                  
          'fields'=>array('Product.title', 'Category.name'))

debug($results); exit;
```

The query no work !! Look at this:

```
 Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Category.name' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Product`.`title`, `Category`.`name`, `Product`.`id` FROM `my_db`.`carts` AS `Cart` LEFT JOIN `my_db`.`products` AS `Product` ON (`Cart`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`) WHERE ((`Product`.`title` LIKE '%apple%') OR (`Category`.`name` LIKE '%apple%'))
```

As you can see the Category data aren't attached to the Product !! If I try the same query with a simple condition (eg. 'Category.name LIKE' => "%$query%") the query works !! So I think that the problem is with the OR condition , but i'm unable to solve it ...

Have suggestions ?

Thx in advance

Comment: I've found an user with a similar trouble. take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386500/cakephp-contain-and-belongsto-hasmany-conditions

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to OR between terms on different tables, I believe you'll have to throw out your relationship for this query and make a manual join instead.  With the manual join, I think you should be able to write conditions how you want.  Perhaps something like this?

```
 $this->Cart->recursive = -1;
 $results = $this->Cart->find('all', 
    array(
      'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'products',
                'alias' => 'Product',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Product.cart_id = Cart.id',
                ),
            ),
      ),
      'conditions'=>array(
                           'OR' => array(
                                'Product.title LIKE' => "%$query%", 
                                'Category.name LIKE' => "%$query%"
                                 )
                         ),                                                  
      'fields'=>array('Product.title', 'Category.name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a condition (Category.name) that doesn't exist in the main model association (Cart and Product). I am not sure about your requirements but a good starting point is changing the query to something like this:

```
 $results = $this->Cart->find('all', 
        array(
          'contain' => array(
              'Product' => array(
                  'Category' => array(
                      'conditions' => array('Category.name LIKE' => "%$query%"),
                      'fields' => array('Category.name')
                   )
              )
           ),
          'conditions'=>array(
              'Product.title LIKE' => "%$query%"
          ),                                                  
         'fields'=> array('Product.title')
        );
```

Bear in mind that this is not the solution, you will have to modify the conditions according to your requirements (As you can see I removed the OR conditions)

Comment: removing the OR condition the query works , but I know that (see the original question above). I need to make it working with the OR ...

Comment: You want to apply an OR condition to different models at different levels, Category (condition here) -> Product (condition here) -> Cart.
Imho you won't be able to do that with just one query (If I am wrong let us know the solution). I also want to [recommend this plugin for complex searches](https://github.com/CakeDC/search)